# 画面非遷移でCGIを実行したい

Tags: html, apache, cgi

ブラウザのボタンクリックにより、サーバーのCGIを実行し、サーバー側のIOを操作したいのです。

ボタンにonclickでCGIにPOSTするようにして見たんですが、処理終了後

End of script output before headers: motor_rotate.cgi
とのエラーが出てしまいます。

たぶんPOSTメソッドはhtmlが帰ってくるのを待っているのかと思うんですが、できればPOSTするだけで画面遷移したくないのですが、そう言ったことは可能でしょうか？
htmlについて、余り詳しくないんですが、ajaxeとかjqueryとかの勉強が必要でしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

はい、まさしく[Ajax](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax)を扱うスキルが必要です。AjaxとはAsynchronous JavaScript + XMLの意味であり、

> 従来のWebアプリケーションでは、サーバにリクエストを送信後、レスポンスを新たにウェブページとして受け取ることで画面遷移が発生していたが、Ajaxにより画面遷移を伴わない動的なWebアプリケーションの製作が実現可能になる。

と説明されている通りです。